# unable to get favicon

Tags: android, favicon

I cant get fav icon from url.
My link looks like
while I have permission on android and tryied to restart my emulator. but still the same result.
The url is

```
http://www.feeds.bbci.co.uk/favicon.ico
```

I tried this

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but the error is on

```
connection.connect();
```

the exception is

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.feeds.bbci.co.uk
```

***Updates****

change the link to

```
URL url = new URL("HTTP://bbc.co.uk/favicon.ico");
```

but now get null on

```
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Comment: but i browser i'm getting `page not found `. make sure server is running or not

Comment: Please this link paste in browser.. in browser also not found.

Comment: The BBC favicon is at http://www.bbc.co.uk/favicon.ico, not the link you're using.

Comment: Icon link is broken, not found.

Comment: please see updates on my main post